# Converting UTF-8 euro char to other euro

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

Somehow there are two different € chars in UTF-8. A [correct one](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20AC/index.htm) U+20AC and [latin-1 supplement](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0080/index.htm) U+0080.

Using `bin2hex` I got hex `c280` instead of the correct `e282ac`. Since the first one is not displayed correctly I would like to convert it.

Officiously I can't use `utf8_decode()` or `utf8_encode()`. I tried `iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $x)` but that gives me `"Â€"` because in Windows-1252 € is `80`.

What is the correct converter for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it does work if I convert from utf8_decode back to Windows-1252 and convert to utf8 again using iconv:

```
iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', utf8_decode($x));
```

I guess the string is originally Windows-1252 and was converted utf8_encode what did not work for most but not all characters.