# How to convert euro (€) symbol from Windows-1252 to UTF-8?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, windows-1252

A software generates me a Windows-1252 XML file, and I would like to parse it in PHP, and send the data on my database in UTF8.

I tried a lot of solutions, such as **iconv** or **utf8_encode** functions, but no result.

It displays things like `Â€`, but not just `€`...

My XML file is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encodoing="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
    <node>The price is 12 &#128; !</node>
```

*`&#128;`* seems to be the code of € (euro) in Windows-1252.

I tried these functions :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='fr'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    </head>

    <body>

<?php
    // XML Loading in DOM Document
    // Parsing XML Node

    /* Not working */
    $node = iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $nodeValue);

    /* Not working */
    $node = utf8_encode($nodeValue);
?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain why the other solutions didn't work.

Comment: Edited a little bit, i don't really know why this isn't working..

Comment: What is "It" in "It displays". Encoding problems can occur anywhere in the chain. I suggest you give a list of steps that cause the problem,  from getting the file to display the output.

Comment: I've edited with my XML head code

Comment: Try to show your php as well ;) And also make sure your project is using the correct encoding (files, html etc.).

Comment: Edited with some parts of my PHP :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329062/converting-utf-8-euro-char-to-other-euro) the Euro symbol is converted to the [latin-1 supplement euro character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0080/index.htm), and not the ["proper" UTF-8 codepoint](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20AC/index.htm). A workaround for it is to `utf8_decode` and then "re-encode" again:
    $node = iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', utf8_decode($node));

So some sample code that works:

```
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
    <node>The price is 12 &#128; !</node>';

$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('node');
$node = iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', utf8_decode($nodes[0]->nodeValue));
echo $node;
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the `Â€`?

Comment: I see the `Â€` instead of simple `€`symbol

Comment: I mean in what interface? on your HTML page?

Comment: Yes, when I print_r my *DOMDocument* content

Comment: Is it as in the HTML above? Does it contain `<meta charset='UTF-8'>`?

Comment: If I set the `<meta charset>` , there won't be any symbol `€` on the page. If I don't specify a charset, there will be `Â€`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79662/discussion-between-akirk-and-hugotor).

Comment: I have modified my answer to reflect the recent findings.

Comment: Ok, with what you say in the chat and here, it just works perfectly ! Thanks a lot man !